# Using imported HTML with own CSS an JS in Angular

Tags: angular, pipe, innerhtml, angular-dom-sanitizer

I store different pages in html to be shown in an router-outlet in some angular-component.

The pages should have their own css-files and their own js-files for logic.

My content-handling-component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentService } from '../content.service';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content-handler',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './content-handler.component.html',
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  styleUrls: ['./content-handler.component.scss'],
})
export class ContentHandlerComponent implements OnInit {
  topic: string = '';
  subtopic: string = '';
  currentContent: SafeHtml = 'test';
  currentSubject: string = 'planeGeo';
  private routeSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(
    private contentService: ContentService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      //console.log(params);
      this.topic = params['topic'];
      this.subtopic = params['subtopic'];
      this.getCurrentContent();
    });
  }

  ngonDestroy(): void {
    if (this.routeSubscription) {
      this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  getCurrentContent() {
    const jsonPath = `assets/models/${this.currentSubject}.json`;
    this.http.get<any>(jsonPath).subscribe((data) => {
      const htmlPath =
        data[this.currentSubject]['topics'][this.topic][this.subtopic][
          'htmlCode'
        ];
      if (htmlPath) {
        this.http
          .get(htmlPath, { responseType: 'text' })
          .subscribe((htmlData) => {
            this.currentContent =
              this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlData);
          });
      } else {
        console.error('HTML-Code nicht gefunden.');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The getCurrentContent()-method gets the path of the html-files from a json, where other data of the corresponding topic is stored, too. It then parses it through the sanitizier.

The corresponding html is just:

```
<div [innerHTML]="currentContent"></div>
```

When I load an html-file with linked css and js-files, they have no effect. I tried different things like creating my own @Pipe like explained [HERE](https://blog.briebug.com/blog/how-do-i-display-html-inside-an-angular-binding), but this didn't work. I also tried to put the css-rules in the global scss-file. That worked, but I dont' have a clue where to put certain js-functions in to make them global.

I think the problem is that the html is only read as a string and so the paths for css and js can't be interpreted right or the DOMSanitizier causes it.

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Do NOT include `[]` characters in your title. Do NOT repeat tag information in your title. Use the space instead to write a **better** title that more clearly explains the problem you're having or question you're asking. For more information about everything I've written, see [ask].